# Ranking the factor variable and the logic

Tags: r

I am trying to rank a factor variable. Though i am able to rank however i am not able to understand the logic behind this.Please let me know if i can use the ranking for my correlation in combination with the numerical variables?And how is ranking logic?

```
> dput(train <- data[train_ind, ])
structure(list(CATEGORY_NAME = structure(c(7L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 13L, 10L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 14L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 13L, 7L, 
5L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 10L, 13L, 7L, 6L, 14L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 
8L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 14L, 4L, 15L, 6L, 5L, 14L, 7L, 13L, 
12L, 14L, 13L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 7L, 14L, 8L, 
14L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 14L, 
6L, 6L, 8L, 14L, 6L, 14L, 4L, 14L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 14L, 14L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 4L, 14L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 
3L), .Label = c("AUDIT", "DEFAULT", "DOCUMENTATION - BILLING", 
"DOCUMENTATION - COLLECTIONS", "DUPLICATE CLAIM", "INCORRECT CLAIM", 
"INCORRECT PAYER", "INVALID AUTHORIZATION", "INVALID DIAGNOSIS", 
"INVALID PRESCRIBER/PROVIDER", "NULL", "PATIENT NOT COVERED", 
"SERVICE NOT COVERED - CLEARANCE", "SERVICE NOT COVERED - COLLECTIONS", 
"TIMELY FILING"), class = "factor"), THERAPY2013ROLLUP = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ADVANCED", 
"CORE", "ONCOLOGY", "RARE"), class = "factor"), PAT_PAYOR_NAME = structure(c(221L, 
63L, 227L, 8L, 8L, 63L, 67L, 280L, 375L, 64L, 8L, 447L, 187L, 
276L, 450L, 116L, 185L, 159L, 447L, 221L, 247L, 442L, 447L, 153L, 
484L, 8L, 395L, 113L, 205L, 63L, 447L, 169L, 275L, 63L, 69L, 
187L, 211L, 66L, 403L, 447L, 64L, 185L, 208L, 447L, 185L, 185L, 
205L, 63L, 280L, 447L, 185L, 63L, 64L, 63L, 113L, 468L, 66L, 
287L, 67L, 8L, 67L, 185L, 185L, 63L, 442L, 447L, 67L, 447L, 447L, 
57L, 8L, 375L, 447L, 280L, 8L, 450L, 70L, 8L, 185L, 185L, 63L, 
442L, 185L, 377L, 185L, 459L, 326L, 447L, 447L, 276L, 8L, 187L, 
288L, 86L, 185L, 252L, 468L, 447L, 210L, 277L, 219L, 185L, 113L, 
447L, 88L, 450L, 187L, 375L, 185L), .Label = c("AARP", "AARP HEALTHCARE OPTIONS", 
"ABBOTT LABORATORIES", "ACCLAIM", "ACCOUNTABLE HEALTH CARE IPA", 
"ADMINISTRATIVE CONCEPTS", "ADVOCATE HEALTH CARE", "AETNA", "AETNA - LUXTURNA ONLY", 
"AETNA - LUXTURNA ONLY\t\t", "AFFINITY MEDICAL GROUP", "AFLAC", 
"ALL SAVERS HEALTH PLAN", "ALLCARE- IPA", "ALLEGIANCE BENEFIT PLAN MANAGEMENT", 
"ALLEN COUNTY REGIONAL HOSPITAL", "ALLIANCE HEALTH AND LIFE", 
"ALLIANT HEALTH PLAN", "ALLIED BENEFIT SYSTEMS INC", "ALLSTATE INSURANCE COMPANY", 
"ALLWAYS HLTH PRTNRS-FKA NHP MASS", "ALTA BATES MEDICAL GROUP", 
"AM FIRST", "AMA INSURANCE AGENCY", "AMBETTER AZ COMPLETE HLTH-LUXTURNA", 
"AMEDISYS HOSPICE\t\t", "AMERAPLAN HRA", "AMERIBEN SOLUTIONS", 
"AMERICAN MEDICAL SECURITY", "AMERICAN NATIONAL INSURANCE COMPANY", 
"AMERICAN POSTAL WORKERS UN HLTH PLN", "AMERICAN POSTAL WORKERS UNION", 
"AMERICAN REPUBLIC INS", "APPLECARE MEDICAL GROUP DRUG ONLY", 
"APWU HEALTH PLAN", "APWU HEALTH PLAN PD NURSING ONLY", "ARISE HEALTH PLAN (FORMERLY WPS)", 
"ASHWAUBENON SCHOOL DISTRICT", "ASSOC AND SOCIETY INSURANCE", 
"ASURIS NORTHWEST HEALTH", "ATLANTIC HEALTH", "AULTCARE", "AURORA HEALTH CARE", 
"AUXIANT", "AUXIANT HEALTH", "AVMED", "BANKERS LIFE & CASUALTY", 
"BAYCARE HOMECARE / MNGD CARE OFF", "BAYLOR UNIVERSITY MEDICAL CENTER", 
"BCBS MT-HEALTH CARE SVC CORP DRUG", "BEAVER MEDICAL GROUP", 
"BORGESS MEDICAL CENTER", "BOSTON MEDICAL CENTER", "BRAZOSPORT REG HEALTHCARE SYSTEMS", 
"BRIGHAM AND WOMEN'S HOSPITAL", "BROOKDALE WESTLAKE HILLS SNF", 
"BROWN & TOLAND MEDICAL GRP", "BROWN & TOLAND PHYSICIANS EAST BAY", 
"BROWN & TOLAND PHYSICIANS WEST BAY", "BUCHANAN METAL FORMING", 
"BUTTERWORTH HOSPITAL", "CAPITAL DISTRICT PHYSICIANS HLTH PL", 
"CARECENTRIX", "CARECENTRIX DRUG ONLY", "CARECENTRIX FL BLUE DRUG ONLY", 
"CARECENTRIX FL BLUE PD PRNV", "CARECENTRIX HORIZ BCBS NJ DRUG ONLY", 
"CARECENTRIX HORIZ BCBS NJ PD PRNV", "CARECENTRIX PD/PRNV ONLY", 
"CARESOURCE", "CAROLINA HEALTH SYSTEMS", "CARPENTERS HEALTH & WELFARE", 
"CARPENTERS UNION", "CAYUGA ONONDAGA AREA SCHOOLS", "CEDARS SINAI HEALTH ASSOCIATES", 
"CEDARS SINAI MEDICAL GROUP", "CENTRAL RESERVE LIFE", "CHANGE HEALTHCARE", 
"CHILDREN'S NATIONAL MEDICAL CTR", "CHILDRENS COMMUNITY HEALTH PLAN", 
"CHILDRENS HOSPITAL", "CHILDRENS HOSPITAL OF PHILADELPHIA", "CHRISTIAN BROTHERS SERVICES", 
"CHRISTIAN CARE MINISTRY MEDI-SHARE", "CHRISTUS SPOHN HOSP SHORELINE", 
"CIGNA", "CIGNA - LUXTURNA ONLY", "CIGNA HEALTHCARE", "CIGNA MEDICAL", 
"CIGNA MEDICAL DRUGS ONLY", "CIGNA MEDICAL FEDEX", "CIGNA MEDICAL FEDEX DRUGS ONLY", 
"CIGNA MEDICAL NURSING ONLY", "CIGNA MEDICAL PER DIEMS ONLY", 
"CIGNA MEDICAL UPS", "CIGNA MEDICAL UPS DRUGS ONLY", "CINCINNATI CLAIMS FOR WORKERS COMP", 
"CITY OF LEXINGTON", "CLALIT HEALTH SERVICES", "CLARION HLTH METHODIST HOSPITAL", 
"CLARK COUNTY SCHOOL DISTRICT", "CLEVELAND CLINIC", "COASTAL COMM PHYSICIAN NETWORK IPA", 
"COFINITY", "COLONIAL MEDICAL INSURANCE CO", "COMBINED INSURANCE CO OF AMERICA", 
"COMMON GROUND HEALTHCARE", "COMMUNITY CARE", "COMMUNITY CARE HEALTH & LIFE", 
"COMMUNITY FIRST HEALTH PLANS", "COMMUNITY HEALTH CHOICE", "COMP MANAGEMENT HEALTH SYSTEMS-SXC", 
"COMPASS ROSE HEALTH PLAN", "COMPMANAGEMENT HEALTH SYSTEMS", 
"CONIFER HEALTH SOLUTIONS", "CONNECTICARE", "CONTRA COSTA HEALTH PLAN", 
"COOK AND COMPANY", "CORPORATE MGD HLTH SVCS-DIVERSIFIED", "COUNTRY LIFE", 
"COVENTRY HEALTH CARE", "COVENTRY HEALTH CARE-MERCY HEALTH", 
"CROWN CORK & SEAL COMPANY INC", "CUSHMAN AND WAKEFIELD", "CVS PHARMACY INC-ZOLGENSMA", 
"DAKOTACARE", "DEAN HEALTH PLAN INC", "DECATUR MEM HOSP-CENTRAL IL HLTH", 
"DESERET MUTUAL BENEFITS", "DEX IMAGING", "DIGNITY HEALTH MEDICAL FOUNDATION", 
"EAST BATON ROUGE SHERIFFS OFFICE", "EAST BOSTON NEIGHBORHOOD HLTH CTR", 
"EASTERN MAINE HEALTH SYSTEM", "EBIX HLTH ADMIN EXCHANGE", "EBMS-EMPLOYEE BENEFIT MGMT SVC", 
"EDUCATORS MUTUAL", "EDWARD C. LEVY", "ELLIS HOSPITAL", "EMBASSY OF SAUDI ARABIA", 
"EMBASSY OF SAUDI ARABIA AFO", "EMBASSY OF THE STATE OF KUWAIT HLTH", 
"EMBASSY OF THE STATE OF QATAR", "EMBASSY OF THE UNITED ARAB EMIRATES", 
"EMI HEALTH", "EMPIRE PHYSICIANS MEDICAL GROUP", "EQUIAN-CATAMARAN", 
"EQUITABLE", "ERIE INSURANCE", "FACILITY HOSPITAL/ PHARMACY", 
"FACILITY HOSPITAL/PHARMACY", "FALLON COMMUNITY HEALTH PLAN", 
"FAMILY CARE SPECIALIST", "FAMILY CARE SPECIALISTS", "FARMERS TELEPHONE COOPERATIVE", 
"FEDERAL REPUBLIC OF GERMANY", "FIDELIS CARE OF NEW YORK", "FIRST CARE", 
"FIRST CAROLINA CARE", "FIRST CHOICE HEALTH", "FIRST CHOICE HEALTH PLAN", 
"FIRST CHOICE MEDICAL GROUP", "FIRSTCARE HEALTH PLANS", "FISHBACK FINANCIAL CORPORATION", 
"FMH BENEFIT SERVICES", "FMH BENEFITS-CORESOURCE", "FORT SANDERS REGIONAL MEDICAL CTR", 
"GARNETT AND COWLES INSURANCE", "GEHA", "GEHA(GOVT EMP HLTH ASSOC)", 
"GEISINGER HEALTH PLAN", "GENERAL BUILDING LABORORS LOCAL 66", 
"GERBER LIFE INSURANCE", "GILBERT PUBLIC SCHOOL", "GILSBAR INC", 
"GLOBAL CARE", "GOLDEN RULE INSURANCE CO", "GOLDEN TRIANGLE SPEC NTWRK DRG ONLY", 
"GOLDEN TRIANGLE SPECIALTY NETWORK", "GREAT AMERICAN LIFE INS", 
"GREENSPRING VILLAGE", "GREENVILLE MEMORIAL MED CNTR", "GROUP & PENSION ADM", 
"GROUP HEALTH COOP SC WISCONSIN", "GROUP HEALTH INC (GHI)", "GROUP HEALTH INC (GHI)-HOME", 
"GROUP HEALTH INC (GHI)-OFFICE", "HALFF ASSOCIATES", "HARTFORD INSURANCE CO", 
"HARTFORD LIFE INSURANCE CO", "HARVARD PILGRIM HEALTH CARE INC", 
"HARVARD PILGRIM HEALTH CARE INC1133", "HEALTH ALLIANCE PLAN", 
"HEALTH ALLIANCE PLAN OF MICHIGAN", "HEALTH CARE LA IPA", "HEALTH CARE PARTNERS", 
"HEALTH CHOICE", "HEALTH CHOICE OF OK", "HEALTH CHOICE OF OKLAHOMA", 
"HEALTH DESIGN PLUS", "HEALTH EZ", "HEALTH FIRST HEALTH PLANS", 
"HEALTH FIRST HEALTH PLANS FLORIDA", "HEALTH NET OF AZ", "HEALTH NET OF CA", 
"HEALTH NET OF OR", "HEALTH NEW ENGLAND", "HEALTH PARTNERS", 
"HEALTH PARTNERS OF MN", "HEALTH PLAN OF NEVADA", "HEALTH PLAN OF UPPER OHIO VALLEY", 
"HEALTH PLANS INC", "HEALTH PLUS PHYSICIANS ORGANIZATION", "HEALTH SELECT", 
"HEALTHCARE PARTNERS", "HEALTHCARE PARTNERS OF NV- IPA", "HEALTHFIRST", 
"HEALTHGRAM", "HEALTHLINK", "HEALTHSCOPE", "HEALTHSMART", "HEALTHSOUTH REHABILITATION HOSPITAL", 
"HENDRICK MANAGEMENT", "HIGH DESERT MEDICAL GROUP", "HILL COUNTRY MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"HILMAR CHEESE COMPANY", "HIP OF NY", "HIP OF NY-HOME", "HISPANIC PHYSICIANS IPA", 
"HOMETOWN HEALTH PLAN", "HOSPICE OF THE WEST", "HOSPITAL/MEDICAL CTR", 
"HUMANA", "HUMANA INC", "HYDRO-GEAR", "IBEW", "IBEW LOCAL 25 HEALTH & BENEFIT FUND", 
"IBEW LOCAL UNION 3", "ILWU-PMA COASTWISE", "IMPERIAL HEALTH HOLDINGS", 
"INDEPENDENT HEALTH ASSOCIATION", "INDIAN HEALTH SERVICES", "INNOVAGE CA PACE", 
"INSURANCE SERVICES OF LUBBOCK", "IOUE LOCAL 825", "JOHNS HOPKINS HEALTHCARE", 
"JOINT IND BRD ELECTRICAL", "JP FARLEY CORPORATION", "KAISER EDI TESTING ONLY", 
"KAISER FOUNDATION HEALTH PLAN", "KAISER FOUNDATION HEALTH PLAN INC", 
"KAISER FOUNDATION HLTPLN WA FKA GHC", "KAISER PERMANENTE", "KAISER PERMANENTE NORTHERN CA", 
"KAISER PERMANENTE OF GEORGIA", "KAISER PERMANENTE OF HAWAII", 
"KAISER PERMANENTE OF NORTHWEST", "KAISER PERMANENTE SELF FUNDED PLAN", 
"KAISER PERMANENTE SOUTHERN CA", "KEARNY MESA RHAB CTR", "KINDRED HOSPICE", 
"KINDRED HOSPITAL", "LIBERTY NATIONAL", "LOCAL 342 WELFARE FUND", 
"LSU FIRST", "M S HERSHEY MEDICAL", "MAGNACARE", "MAILHANDLERS", 
"MARIS GROVE INC", "MARSH AFFINITY GROUP SERVICES", "MASSACHUSETTS GENERAL HOSPITAL", 
"MAYO HEALTH SYSTEMS", "MCLAREN HEALTH PLAN", "MCS  LIFE INSURANCE", 
"MED PAY", "MEDICA", "MEDICA CHOICE", "MEDICAL CENTER", "MEDICAL CENTER OF GEORGIA", 
"MEDICAL MUTUAL OF OHIO", "MEDONE PHARMACY SERVICES", "MEMBERS HEALTH INSURANCE", 
"MEMORIAL HEALTH CARE IPA", "MEMORIAL HEALTHCARE SYSTEM", "MERCY CARE HEALTH PLAN", 
"MERCY PHYSICIANS MEDICAL GROUP", "MERITAGE MED NTWK FKA MARIN SONOMA", 
"MERITAIN HEALTH", "MIDWEST POULTRY SERVICES", "MISSION HOSPITAL INCORPORATED", 
"MODA HEALTH", "MOHEGAN TRIBE OF CT", "MONARCH HEALTHCARE", "MONARCH MEDICAL GROUP", 
"MONTEFIORE CMO", "MUSICIANS LOCAL 802", "MUTUAL OF OMAHA", "MVP HEALTH PLAN", 
"MVP HEALTHCARE", "NASI - NATIONAL AUTOMATIC SPRINKLER", "NATIONAL BENEFIT FUND 1199", 
"NATIONAL POSTAL MAIL HANDLERS", "NATIONWIDE INSURANCE", "NEIGHBORHOOD HEALTH PLAN MASS", 
"NETWORK HEALTH PLAN MCARE ADVANTAGE", "NEW MEXICO MEDICAL INSURANCE POOL", 
"NEW MEXICO MEDICAL INSURANCE POOL\t", "NEW MEXICO MEDICAL INSURANCE POOL\t\t", 
"NEW YORK CITY LAW DEPT", "NEW YORK HOTEL TRADE", "NEW YORK UNIVERSITY", 
"NEXCALIBER", "NIVANO PHYS DBA SIERRA NV MED ASSOC", "NJ CARPENTER HEALTH FUND", 
"NOBLE HORIZONS", "NORTH AMERICA ADMINISTRATORS", "NORTH TX SPECIALTY PHYSICIANS", 
"NORTH TX SPECIALTY PHYSICIANS\t\t", "NORTHEAST GA MEDICAL HLTH PARTNERS", 
"NORTHERN IL HEALTH PLAN", "NYSTROM & ASSOCIATES LTD", "OCONEE REGIONAL", 
"OLYMPUS MANAGED HEALTHCARE INC", "ONEIDA NATION OF WISCONSIN", 
"OPTIMA", "OPTIMA HEALTH", "OPTIMA HEALTH PLAN", "OPTUM CARE NETWORK CONNECTICUT", 
"OSI ENVIRONMENTAL", "OXFORD HEALTH PLAN", "PACE WORKERS COMP-MAGELLAN", 
"PACIFIC SOURCE HEALTH PLANS", "PALM BEACH COUNTY FIREFIGHTERS", 
"PAM SPECIALTY HOSPITAL COVINGTON", "PARAGON BENEFITS INC", "PARAMOUNT", 
"PARK CITY PRESBYTERIAN", "PEKIN LIFE INSURANCE", "PETERSON, BEYENHOF & ZAHLER LTD", 
"PHP OF MID MICHIGAN", "PHYSICIANS MED GRP SANTA CRUZ", "PHYSICIANS OF SW WASHINGTON", 
"PHYSICIANS PLUS INSURANCE CORP", "PLANNED ADMINISTRATORS INC (PAI)", 
"PLUMBERS & PIPEFITTERS", "POMCO", "POMONA VALLEY MEDICAL GROUP", 
"PREFERRED HEALTH PROFESSIONALS", "PREFERRED ONE ADMINISTRATIVE SERVIC", 
"PREFERRED ONE COMMUNITY HEALTH PLAN", "PRESBYTERIAN HEALTH PLAN", 
"PRIMECARE MED NTWK-CORONA", "PRIMECARE MED NTWK-HEMET VALLEY", 
"PRIMECARE MED NTWK-PHYSICIAN NTWK", "PRIMECARE MED NTWK-TEMECULA", 
"PRIMECARE MED NTWK - CORONA", "PRINCIPAL LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", 
"PRIORITY HEALTH", "PRIVATE HEALTH CARE SYSTEMS", "PROSPECT MEDICAL GROUP", 
"PROVIDENCE HEALTH PLAN", "PROVIDRS CARE NETWORK FKA WPPA", "PUBLIC EMPLOYEES HEALTH PLAN", 
"QUAL CHOICE OF ARKANSAS", "QUALCARE", "QUALCHOICE OF ARKANSAS", 
"QUIKTRIP", "RATHJE ENTERPRISES INC", "REGAL MEDICAL GROUP", 
"REHABILITATION HOSPITAL OF IN", "RIVER CITY MEDICAL GROUP", 
"RUSH UNIVERSITY MEDICAL CENTER", "SALT RIVER PROJECT", "SAMBA", 
"SANFORD HEALTH PLAN", "SANTA BARBARA SELECT", "SCOTT & WHITE HEALTH PLAN", 
"SCOTTSDALE HEALTH CARE", "SEAMAN CORPORATION", "SEAVIEW MEDICAL GROUP", 
"SECURITY HEALTH PLAN", "SELECT CARE", "SELECT HEALTH FKA INTERMOUNTAIN", 
"SELECT HEALTH FORMERLY IHC", "SELMAN AND COMPANY", "SENTARA HEALTH MANAGEMENT", 
"SENTARA HEALTHCARE", "SENTRY INSURANCE WORKERS COMP", "SERVICE EMPLOYEES INTL UNION (SEIU)", 
"SHARP COMMUNITY MEDICAL GROUP", "SHARP HEALTH CARE", "SHARP HEALTH PLAN", 
"SHEPPARD PRATT HOSPITAL", "SHILAND FAMILY MEDICINE", "SIERRA HEALTH & LIFE", 
"SIERRA HEALTH AND LIFE", "SIERRA HEALTH SERVICES", "SIERRA MEDICAL GROUP", 
"SOUTHEAST GEORGIA REG MED CENTER", "SOUTHWESTERN HEALTH RESOURCES", 
"SPECTRA ENERGY", "SPRAYING SYSTEMS CO", "ST JOSEPH HERITAGE HEALTH", 
"ST JOSEPH HERITAGE HEALTHCARE", "ST JOSEPH HOSPITAL", "ST JUDE HERITAGE MEDICAL GROUP", 
"ST MARYS HOSPITAL", "ST VINCENT MEDICAL GROUP", "ST. JOHN'S HOSPITAL", 
"STATE FARM HEALTH CARE CLAIMS", "STATE OF ILLINOIS EMPLOYEES", 
"STATE OF NEVADA", "STEWART C MILLER COMPANY INC", "STEWART TILE", 
"STONERIVER PHARMACY SOLUTIONS", "SUBURBAN EMPLOYEE SERVICES", 
"SUFFOLK COUNTY RISK MANAGEMENT", "SUMMACARE", "SUTTER HEALTH", 
"SUTTER MEDICAL FOUNDATION", "SYCUAN BAND OF THE KUMEYAAY NATION", 
"SYRACUSE CITY SCHOOLS", "TAMPA GENERAL HOSPITAL", "TEAMSTERS HEALTH & WELFARE", 
"TEAMSTERS WESTERN REGION LOCAL 177", "TERREBONNE SCHOOL BOARD", 
"THE EDGEWOOD CENTRE", "THE HEALTH PLAN OF THE UPPER OH VLY", 
"TOLEDO ELECTRICAL WELFARE FUND", "TRANSAMERICA LIFE (FKA STONEBRIDGE)", 
"TRI STATE HEALTH AND WELFARE", "TUFTS HEALTH PLAN", "UC SAN DIEGO HEALTH", 
"UCLA MEDICAL GROUP DRUG ONLY", "UFCW", "UFCW-UNITE", "UFCW & EMPLOYERS AZ HEALTH TRUST", 
"UFCW & PFIE HEALTH AND WELFARE", "UHC - ALL SAVERS PLAN", "UHC PASSPORT CONNECT HARVARD PILGR.", 
"UHC WEST FKA PACIFICARE", "UMR", "UNICARE HEALTH PLAN", "UNICARE STATE INDEMNITY PLAN", 
"UNIFIED GROUP SERVICES", "UNITED FOOD & COMMRCL WORKERS 880", 
"UNITED HEALTH CARE", "UNITED HEALTH ONE", "UNITED HEALTH SHARED SERVICES", 
"UNITED HEALTHCARE", "UNITED HEALTHCARE-EMPIRE", "UNITED HEALTHCARE-EMPIRE.", 
"UNITED HEALTHCARE-SIERRA HEALTH", "UNITED HEALTHCARE - HCAP", 
"UNITED HEALTHCARE  EMPIRE PLAN", "UNITED HEALTHCARE CHOICE PLUS-ZLGN", 
"UNITED HEALTHCARE HCAP", "UNITED HEALTHCARE INTERNATIONAL", 
"UNITED HEALTHCARE STUDENT RESOURCES", "UNITY HEALTH PLAN", "UNIV HOSPTAL NORTH SHORE", 
"UNIV OF MEDICINE & DENISTRY OF NJ", "UNIVERA HEALTHCARE", "UNIVERSITY HEALTH ALLIANCE", 
"UNIVERSITY HEALTH CARE PLUS", "UNIVERSITY OF UTAH HEALTH PLAN", 
"UNIVERSITY OF UTAH NETWORK", "UPMC HEALTH PLAN", "UPMC HEALTH PLAN ESI PD PRNV", 
"US DEPT OF LABOR", "USAA LIFE INSURANCE", "UTE ENERGY", "VALLEY CARE IPA", 
"VALLEY HEALTH PLAN", "VALLEY PRESBYTERIAN HOSPITAL", "VANTAGE MEDICAL GROUP", 
"VIDANT HEALTH", "VILLIAGE OF ROSEMONT", "WA STATE FUND DEPT OF LABOR", 
"WASHINGTON STATE HEALTH INS POOL", "WASHOE COUNTY SCHOOL DISTRICT", 
"WEA TRUST", "WEB TPA", "WEBTPA", "WELLDYNERX", "WELLMED FL", 
"WELLMED TX", "WESTAR ENERGY", "WESTCHESTER COUNTY BENEFITS", 
"WESTERN HEALTH ADVANTAGE", "WESTERN SOUTHERN LIFE", "WESTWOOD CENTER", 
"WINCHESTER MEDICAL CENTER", "WORLD INSURANCE", "WTC HEALTH PROGRAM", 
"WV PEIA", "YAVAPAI REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", "YORK RISK SERVICES-EXPRESS SCRIPTS"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -109L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Below is the code for ranking

```
train_rank<-train%>%select_if(is.factor)%>%mutate_all(funs(dense_rank(desc(.))))
```

Comment: Hi @Numita, those columns are already factors with levels. What do you mean by rank? To sort them according to their levels or something else

Comment: Actually i would like to do a correlation check of all the variables in my dateset. However there where some factor variables in the datasets. so i thought i should rank my factor variables and use the rank as one of the variables along with my numeric variable to run the correlation. But i am not sure, if my logic and assumption is right or wrong?

Comment: see answer below, a bit too long to type as comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense at all. If you look at your levels now:

```
levels(train$CATEGORY_NAME)
 [1] "AUDIT"                             "DEFAULT"                          
 [3] "DOCUMENTATION - BILLING"           "DOCUMENTATION - COLLECTIONS"      
 [5] "DUPLICATE CLAIM"                   "INCORRECT CLAIM"                  
 [7] "INCORRECT PAYER"                   "INVALID AUTHORIZATION"            
 [9] "INVALID DIAGNOSIS"                 "INVALID PRESCRIBER/PROVIDER"      
[11] "NULL"                              "PATIENT NOT COVERED"              
[13] "SERVICE NOT COVERED - CLEARANCE"   "SERVICE NOT COVERED - COLLECTIONS"
[15] "TIMELY FILING"
```

The levels will decide how your variables are ranked. And you can see now they are  sorted alphabetically. When you call rank, this is what happens:

```
data.frame(fac=head(train$CATEGORY_NAME),rank=head(rank(train$CATEGORY_NAME),6))
                          fac rank
1             INCORRECT PAYER 59.0
2       INVALID AUTHORIZATION 69.5
3 DOCUMENTATION - COLLECTIONS 20.0
4 DOCUMENTATION - COLLECTIONS 20.0
5             DUPLICATE CLAIM 32.0
6             INCORRECT CLAIM 46.0
```

You get a rank based on their alphabetical order... and if you do correlation with this on other columns, it makes absolutely no sense at all.